# Press back button twice to exit an AIR android application

Tags: android, air, exit, toast, back

I've noticed this pattern in a lot of Android apps and games recently: when clicking the back button to "exit" the application, a Toast comes up with a message similar to "Press BACK again to exit". After a long time searching, I find an ANE extension showing a nice toast in my app, I have tested it and it's work fine after clicking the back button, now I want to close my app after clicking the back button twice, with delay of 3 seconds, using a force code exit 
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit(0);

ANE Extension:
https://github.com/mateuszmackowiak/NativeDialogs

My Code:

```
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import pl.mateuszmackowiak.nativeANE.notifications.Toast;

stop();

NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, CheckKeypress);

function CheckKeypress(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
        case Keyboard.BACK:
            trace("Back key is pressed.");
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            Toast.show("Press Back again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            break;

        case Keyboard.MENU:
            trace("Menu key is pressed.");
            break;

        case Keyboard.SEARCH:
            trace("Search key is pressed.");
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your MainActivity. Might help.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finishAffinity();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use onBackPressed() in your activity. When the user press back button. this method will be invoked. I think the following code will helps you.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(initialClickTime == 0){
        initialClickTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //Toast with msg press again to exit
    }else{
       if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - initialClickTime)/1000 == 3){
           finish();
       }else{
           initialClickTime = 0;
           //Toast with msg press again to exit
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
    super.onBackPressed();
    return;
}

this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
    doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;                       
}
}, 2000);
}
```